# How do I resolve an "Unknown Host Exception" when using Volley to interact with BigCommerce's Orders API endpoint?

Tags: android-volley, bigcommerce, orders

As far as I know, I am implementing Volley correctly, and I know for a fact that the API endpoint URL along with all the HTTP headers are 100% correct. Yet, when I try to GET the JSON from the endpoint, an Unknown Host Exception is thrown.

I used the BigCommerce Orders API reference and made multiple test queries, and it worked there, but there appears to be some kind of disconnect when ran on the emulator on Android studio. Is it possible that my business' WiFi and/or the emulator itself is causing this problem?

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.start();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET,
            URL, null, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            parseOrders(response);
        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Volley", error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("accept", "application/json");
            params.put("content-type", "application/json");
            params.put("x-auth-token", "myToken");
            params.put("x-auth-client", "myClientID");

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: is your store the only url with that issue? what about a simple GET to www.google.com?

Comment: Sorry about the delay in response! As it turns out, I tried a cold boot of the emulator out of desperation, which seemed to do the trick. I don't know enough about how the emulator works to say why...

Comment: congratulations - https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_IT_Crowd#Yesterday's_Jam_[1.1]

Comment: Hey, seems like you implemented an android app using BigCommerce APIs. I am trying to do the same for ios. Can you please tell me, how did you handle the checkout. Did you used the BC checkout API and did the PCI compliance for that. 
Thanks in advance